# CPU intesive OpenGL functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenGL to create a simulation. 
And I use the keboard inputs to make certain changes in the variables and the update is seen on the window that was created.

However there is a small delay between after I press the key and the changed output on the window.

I tried using the Visual Studio Diagnostic tools and saw that there were 2 key functions that was CPU intensive.

One was a user function that I created and another was 'display/main/__tmainCRTStartup/mainCRTStartup

I'm assuming this a GLUT function. So is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
 switch (key)
 {
    case 'r': case 'R':
    if (filling==0)
    {
        glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); 
        filling=1;
    }
    else
    {
        glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINT); 
        filling=0;
    }
    break;
    case 27:
    exit(0);
    break;
 }
}
```

.

```
void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
glRotatef(-90,0.0,1.0,0.0); 
glRotatef(-90,1.0,0.0,0.0); 

rotation_x = rotation_x + (rotation_x_increment - rotation_x)/50;
rotation_y = rotation_y + (rotation_y_increment - rotation_y)/50;
rotation_z = rotation_z + rotation_z_increment;

if (rotation_x > 359) rotation_x = 0;
if (rotation_y > 359) rotation_y = 0;
if (rotation_z > 359) rotation_z = 0;

if(rotation_x_increment > 359) rotation_x_increment = 0;
if(rotation_y_increment > 359) rotation_y_increment = 0;
if(rotation_z_increment > 359) rotation_z_increment = 0;

glRotatef(rotation_x,1.0,0.0,0.0); 
glRotatef(rotation_y,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glRotatef(rotation_z,0.0,0.0,1.0);

glTranslatef(x_translate,0.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,y_translate,0.0);
glTranslatef(0,0,z_translate); 


glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers(); 
glFlush(); // This force the execution of OpenGL commands
}
```

.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
IntroDisplay();
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(screen_width,screen_height);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("Ultrasonic Testing");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc (resize);
glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);
glutSpecialFunc (keyboard_s);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
init();
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mainCRTStartup` is the runtime library parent function that calls your `main`.  So all it's telling you is that `main` is taking a lot of time, which is reasonable.

Comment: I would try adding a Sleep(0) or Sleep(10) to that loop to see if it makes any difference, and also remove the glFlush();

Comment: Stop using fixed pipeline,maybe it will run faster ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied the code to a new project, i've changed the display function to draw a triangle and it works very fast.

(I know it should be a comment,  not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to add comments).

PD: You can change

```
glTranslatef(x_translate,0.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,y_translate,0.0);
glTranslatef(0,0,z_translate);
```

to

```
glTranslatef(x_translate,y_translate,z_translate);
```